# How to order not in stock items last

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    product
INNER JOIN productcontent ON product.id = productcontent.productID
WHERE
    product.deactivate <> '1'
AND productcontent.price > 0 { $level1SQL }
AND menulevel IN ($imploded)
OR menulevel = '$menulevelID' { $level1SQL }
ORDER BY
    (
        CASE
        WHEN discountPrice < price
        AND discountPrice > 0 THEN
            CAST(
                discountPrice AS DECIMAL (10, 2)
            )
        ELSE
            CAST(
                price AS DECIMAL (10, 2)
            )
        END
    ) { $price_order }
LIMIT { $limit }
```

but I also need to make sure that if the `product.notInStock` set to `1`, it is being ordered at the very end (but still by name / price if such sorting is selected), is it even possible or should I just use 2 queries - one for products that are in stock and one for those that aren't ?

Comment: Perhaps you want `AND (menulevel IN ($imploded)
OR menulevel = '$menulevelID' { $level1SQL })`?

Comment: What are the possible values for `notInStock`, 0 and 1? Then simply add it as first Order By column, otherwise apply another CASE. Btw, are you sure the WHERE-conditions returns the correct rows without parens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional key to the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p INNER JOIN 
     productcontent pc
     ON p.id = pc.productID
WHERE p.deactivate <> '1' AND
      pc.price > 0 {$level1SQL} AND
      (menulevel IN ($imploded) OR menulevel = '$menulevelID')
      {$level1SQL}
ORDER BY p.not_inStock DESC,
         (case when discountPrice < price and discountPrice > 0
               then CAST(discountPrice AS DECIMAL(10,2))
               else CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
          end) {$price_order}
LIMIT {$limit}
```

Also, the last condition on `menulevel` suggests that you need parentheses.